# Is there a way to create an instance method that (de)serializes object with marshal?

Tags: ruby, serialization, marshalling

I have a class like this:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :a, :b
end
```

Is there a way to write an instance method that would (de)serialize this object with marshal like this:

```
class MyClass
  attr_accessor :a, :b
  def load(file)
    #??
  end
  def save(file)
    #??
  end
end
```

I've been saving it like this:

```
File.open("#{SAVE_PATH}/stats", "wb") {|f| f.write(Marshal.dump(stats))
```

and loading:

```
stats = Marshal.load(File.binread("#{SAVE_PATH}/stats"))
```

It works, but I'd like to clean up my code.

Comment: Aren't the codes for saving and loading the other way around?

Comment: @sawa yeah, my bad. Edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got all the pieces you need. Why not just assemble them? How about:

```
def self.load
  Marshal.load(File.binread("#{SAVE_PATH}/stats"))
end

def save
  File.open("#{SAVE_PATH}/stats", "wb") do |f|
    f.write(Marshal.dump(self))
  end
end
```

Note that `load` is better as a class method since it returns an instance of an object. The `save` method can be an instance method since you can use `self` as the thing to save.

If the path where you're persisting things doesn't change you might want to define a constant for that as well to avoid repeating it in both methods.